# Does using Hypnotic Gaze end my Invisibility?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

I wanted to know if using Hypnotic Gaze from the Wizard's enchantment specialization would end invisibility.

RAW, I would think Hypnotic Gaze would be classified as a class feature instead of a spell or attack, thus not ending Invisibility.  A fellow player in our session made an argument against this line of thought, as he claimed that Hypnotic Gaze would be a spell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hypnotic Gaze is not a spell, nor is it an attack. It's an effect granted by a class feature. By RAW it does not cause invisibility to end.

However, since it's *like* a spell and affects another creature in a similar manner *to a spell,* DMs would be well within bounds to rule that using that ability would end invisibility (this should come with a warning prior to use).

Answer (score -4):

You actually can't use Hypnotic Gaze while invisible, as the target must be able to see *and* hear you for it to have any effect. If you use it while invisible, nothing happens, and if you go invisible, or even walk out of their line of sight while it's active, it ends.

edit: Sorry, it's either see or hear. My bad!

Comment: Does "hear" matter with this effect?  You might want to expand on that by editing that point into your answer.

Comment: Don't signal edits. Edit the answer itself so it makes sense and the reader doesn't have to read the bottom to know that something was wrong.